# Grails autoReconnect with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, grails, reconnect

I'm looking for this information, because everytime SQL Server goes down and ,later, goes up, my Grails 4.0.3 is not able to automatically reconnect with the database.

I don't which configuration to use. In my `application.yml` I tested `autoReconnect=true` at the end of the string connection, but it did not work as expected.

```
url: jdbc:sqlserver://${DATABASE_HOST};databaseName=${CMBARQ_DATABASE_NAME};domain=${DATABASE_INSTANCENAME};autoReconnect=true
```

Later I saw in the internet this configuration in `application.yml`, but I think it is exclusive for MySQL, because in all pages I saw it, the database use was MySQL. And I need a configuration like this for SQL Server.

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            properties:
                dbProperties:
                    autoReconnect: true
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Base on [4.0.3 Configuration](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.3/guide/conf.html) ... have you tried pooling with `testOnBorrow`, `testWhileIdle` and a `validationQuery`?

Comment: No,I haven't. I will try it. Thank you.